# C# Convert image to black

Tags: c#, image

i need convert to Black this image.
need to convert image totally dark for simulate a shadow.

"not black and white process. need totally dark"

example

[image]

before converte image totally black 
how to stretch in horizzontal type this image?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: my project is this. https://a.fsdn.com/con/app/proj/mmorpgmaker/screenshots/81335060.png need to simulate shadow but dont know perfectly the process.

Comment: You'll need to draw shadows separately for each meeple.  It's not possible to process the entire image at once because you need the shadows to be lined up at the meeple's feet.  There are 4 feet in total, and their positions are not co-linear; therefore it's not possible to skew the image with a linear transformation while keeping the position of the feet fixed.